# Updating data in SQLite database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I know this question has been asked many times in this site in many different ways but none seems to work for me.
I need to update data to my database from an activity.
I used this code:

```
public class EditAccount extends Activity {

private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
......
}
public void update_acc(View view){
        EditText accName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.acc_name);
        EditText comment=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.comments);
        String acc_name=accName.getText().toString();
        String comments=comment.getText().toString();
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        int id =(int) intent.getExtras().getLong("data_id"); 
        String data_id= Integer.valueOf(id).toString();

        //When i debug the app it comes here and stops:
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL("Update comments set acc_name='"+acc_name+"', 
    comment='"+comments+"' where id="+id, null);
        database.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Account updated; Acc Name:"+acc_name+" Comment:"+comments, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onBackPressed();}
```

Please take a look and see if there are any problems.
Please help!

Thanks in advance,
Waiting for your reply...

Comment: Please say what the error your seeing or why it is not working is and if there is an error in the logcat please post it

Comment: Are you initializing dbHelper?

Comment: how do I get the errors from the logCat?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: never mind..i got the solution

Comment: Thanks by the way for atleast showing interest. @PX Developer

Answer (score 1):

Its done like this:

```
        EditText accName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.acc_name);
        EditText comment=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.comments);
        String acc_name=accName.getText().toString();
        String comments=comment.getText().toString();
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        int id =(int) intent.getExtras().getLong("data_id"); 
        String data_id= Integer.valueOf(id).toString();

        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
          String query="Update comments set acc_name='"+acc_name+"', comment='"+comment+"' where _id="+id;
          database.execSQL(query);

        //Leave a message and go back
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Account updated; Acc_name:"+acc_name+", Comment:"+comments, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onBackPressed();
```